# Finding total sum of loop after finding all powers of 2 below certain number

Tags: java, loops, sum, stringbuilder

I'm new to java/programming in general and this is a homework assignment. This is what I have so far: When I run it I get the powers of 2 below the n input. example if n = 50, output is 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 + = -2
I would like the + after 32 to be gone and I don't know how to properly sum it. I would want the sum to = 62 in this case. I tried using string builder to take off the last two characters but that isn't working for me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Powers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n;
        System.out.print("Enter the upper limit: ");
        n = scan.nextInt();

        int sum = 0;
        int power = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            power = 2 * power;

            if (power < n && 0 < power) {
                System.out.print(power + " + ");
            }
            sum = sum + power;

        }

        System.out.println(" = " + sum);

    }
}
```

Comment: Format your code.  Try a debugger

Comment: Im super new to programming and my prof isn't so great. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: You'll probably also want to use "long" instead of "int", because 32-bit (signed) integers can only store numbers up to (2^31-1). If you want to go beyond n=62, you may even need the BigInteger class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues here:

- When reaching the upper limit you simply stop doing the output but continue doing the summation.
- You use the upper limit as the number of iterations, so in case of `50` in your example, you do a sum of all values between 1 and 2^50, which is the reason why the result is negative, because the sum became larger than the maximum number an `int` can keep.

Concerning your question how to break a loop, there is `break` ;-)

Your print is always outputting a `+` which is why you have the `+ =` in your output. Change the output to something like this:

```
if (power < n && 0 < power) {
    if (i != 0) {
        System.out.print(" + ");
    }
    System.out.print(power);
}
```

Comment: Your formatting on my code actually helped the sum come out correct. But sorry in my question the n is referencing the total sum value. so if the input number is 50 it's not = 2^50, it's showing all 2^x that  < 50. So in this example it shows up until 2^5 = 32 and stops there, because 2^6 is > 50. So now my current issue is just removing that last " + ". And when I try to use that if statement, it returns an incorrect sum again

Comment: And another thing I realized I'm doing wrong is that I need to show the 2^0, which would make the first number 1, and I can't figure out how to do that either

Comment: @Bianca You can do the recalculation of `power` at the end of the `for`-loop or use `Math.pow(2, i)` instead. If `50` should be the upper limit of the sum, change your `if`-statement accordingly by checking the value of `sum` rather than `power`.

Answer (score 0):

I've added some functionality to your code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Type number:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = 0;
        while (n == 0) { // to ask again if "n" is zero.
            n = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        if (n != 0) {
            scanner.close(); // to prevent resource leak
            int sum = 0;
            int power = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                power *= 2;
                sum += power;
                System.out.print(power + " ");
                if (sum + power * 2 < 0 | i == n - 1) {
                    // Should we step to the next iteration?
                    // If next "sum" will be bigger than the max value for
                    // integers
                    // or if this iteration is the last - it will type "sum",
                    // break "for" cycle and go the next line of code after
                    // "for" cycle.
                    // So in this case System.out.print("+ "); won't be
                    // executed.
                    System.out.print("= " + sum);
                    break;
                }
                System.out.print("+ ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```